# Should I have a distinct CI/CD for dev and prod or can I have one for all of my environments and applications in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a monorepo where a lot of applications and libs are build.
I tried to make the CI/CD process the more readable and performant as possible.
Problem is I'm not so familiar with all the possibilites azure pipeline give me.

Should I have a pipeline for each environement? for each app? or can I create only one and using tags or something like that?

thanks

Comment: yes to all. You can do all of these - and each have pros and cons. Which totally depend on your exact use case. I'm sorry but I think your question is too broad and lacking a detailed question in it for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monorepo, you can create one pipeline for all applications, or create individual CI/CD for each one. It depends on how you define in the pipeline.

One pipeline for all: you can use different stages, file path filter, conditions...etc to isolate the builds&testing of application, add stage/job name to display which application it's building.

Individual pipeline: define more pipelines for each application, but could be more readable.

There is a [monorepo pipeline sample](https://github.com/julie-ng/azure-pipelines-monorepo) which has one pipeline and seperate pipelines, you can choose the best way for your project.